# How to get ACS token out from raw token we get Identity Provider

Tags: azure, acs

I am getting the token from acs as describe in this post [Validating a SWT Token REST WCF Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8931287/validating-a-swt-token-rest-wcf-service/8949763#8949763)

But i was not able to extract the ACS token.
Could you please help me in that.
Actually the class the extract the acs token "JsonNotifyRequestSecurityTokenResponse.FromJson"
I was not able to get that as the class as the link provided is not working.

Comment: Hi, it's already a week ago since I answered your question. Did it help? If no: add a comment, if yes: accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think you posted this question as an answer at my question some hours ago and then deleted it. So i looked up my old project and found the code you need:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.IdentityModel.Policy;
using System.IdentityModel.Tokens;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Json;
using System.Text;
using System.Web;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using Thinktecture.IdentityModel.Extensions;

namespace Security {
    [DataContract]
    public class JsonNotifyRequestSecurityTokenResponse {
        [DataMember(Name = "appliesTo", Order = 1)]
        public string AppliesTo { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "context", Order = 2)]
        public string Context { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "created", Order = 3)]
        public string Created { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "expires", Order = 4)]
        public string Expires { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "securityToken", Order = 5)]
        public string SecurityTokenString { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "tokenType", Order = 6)]
        public string TokenType { get; set; }

        public DateTime ValidFrom { get; set; }
        public DateTime ValidTo { get; set; }
        public GenericXmlSecurityToken SecurityToken { get; set; }

        public static JsonNotifyRequestSecurityTokenResponse FromJson(string jsonString) {
            JsonNotifyRequestSecurityTokenResponse rstr;

            var memoryStream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(jsonString));
            var serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(JsonNotifyRequestSecurityTokenResponse));

            rstr = serializer.ReadObject(memoryStream) as JsonNotifyRequestSecurityTokenResponse;
            memoryStream.Close();

            ParseValues(rstr);
            return rstr;
        }

        private static void ParseValues(JsonNotifyRequestSecurityTokenResponse rstr) {
            rstr.ValidFrom = ulong.Parse(rstr.Created).ToDateTimeFromEpoch();
            rstr.ValidTo = ulong.Parse(rstr.Expires).ToDateTimeFromEpoch();
            rstr.SecurityTokenString = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(rstr.SecurityTokenString);
            var xml = XElement.Parse(rstr.SecurityTokenString);

            string idAttribute = "";
            string tokenType = "";

            switch (rstr.TokenType) {
                case SecurityTokenTypes.Saml11:
                    idAttribute = "AssertionID";
                    tokenType = SecurityTokenTypes.Saml11;
                    break;
                case SecurityTokenTypes.Saml2:
                    idAttribute = "ID";
                    tokenType = SecurityTokenTypes.Saml2;
                    break;
                case SecurityTokenTypes.SWT:
                    idAttribute = "Id";
                    tokenType = SecurityTokenTypes.SWT;
                    break;
            }

            if (tokenType == SecurityTokenTypes.Saml11 || tokenType == SecurityTokenTypes.Saml2) {
                var tokenId = xml.Attribute(idAttribute);
                var xmlElement = xml.ToXmlElement();
                SecurityKeyIdentifierClause clause = null;

                if (tokenId != null) {
                    clause = new SamlAssertionKeyIdentifierClause(tokenId.Value);
                }

                rstr.SecurityToken = new GenericXmlSecurityToken(
                     xmlElement,
                     null,
                     rstr.ValidFrom,
                     rstr.ValidTo,
                     clause,
                     clause,
                     new ReadOnlyCollection<IAuthorizationPolicy>(new List<IAuthorizationPolicy>()));
            }
        }

        private class SecurityTokenTypes {
            public const string Saml2 = "urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion";
            public const string Saml11 = "urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.0:assertion";
            public const string SWT = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2009/11/swt-token-profile-1.0";
        }
    }
}
```

You should get the `Thinktecture.IdentityModel.Extensions` assembly from: http://identitymodel.codeplex.com/

I hope this helps.

**EDIT - SWT token handling**

I don't know if it helps, but I've found a `SWTModule` which should handle a SWT token.

```
public class SWTModule : IHttpModule {

    void IHttpModule.Dispose() {

    }

    void IHttpModule.Init(HttpApplication context) {
        context.BeginRequest += new EventHandler(context_BeginRequest);
    }

    void context_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        //HANDLE SWT TOKEN VALIDATION
        // get the authorization header
        string headerValue = HttpContext.Current.Request.Headers.Get("Authorization");

        // check that a value is there
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(headerValue)) {
            throw new ApplicationException("unauthorized");
        }

        // check that it starts with 'WRAP'
        if (!headerValue.StartsWith("WRAP ")) {
            throw new ApplicationException("unauthorized");
        }

        string[] nameValuePair = headerValue.Substring("WRAP ".Length).Split(new char[] { '=' }, 2);

        if (nameValuePair.Length != 2 ||
             nameValuePair[0] != "access_token" ||
             !nameValuePair[1].StartsWith("\"") ||
             !nameValuePair[1].EndsWith("\"")) {
            throw new ApplicationException("unauthorized");
        }

        // trim off the leading and trailing double-quotes
        string token = nameValuePair[1].Substring(1, nameValuePair[1].Length - 2);

        // create a token validator
        TokenValidator validator = new TokenValidator(
             this.acsHostName,
             this.serviceNamespace,
             this.trustedAudience,
             this.trustedTokenPolicyKey);

        // validate the token
        if (!validator.Validate(token)) {
            throw new ApplicationException("unauthorized");
        }

    }
}
```

And you also need the `TokenValidator`:

```
public class TokenValidator {
    private string issuerLabel = "Issuer";
    private string expiresLabel = "ExpiresOn";
    private string audienceLabel = "Audience";
    private string hmacSHA256Label = "HMACSHA256";

    private string acsHostName;

    private string trustedSigningKey;
    private string trustedTokenIssuer;
    private string trustedAudienceValue;

    public TokenValidator(string acsHostName, string serviceNamespace, string trustedAudienceValue, string trustedSigningKey) {
        this.trustedSigningKey = trustedSigningKey;
        this.trustedTokenIssuer = String.Format("https://{0}.{1}/",
             serviceNamespace.ToLowerInvariant(),
             acsHostName.ToLowerInvariant());

        this.trustedAudienceValue = trustedAudienceValue;
    }

    public bool Validate(string token) {
        if (!this.IsHMACValid(token, Convert.FromBase64String(this.trustedSigningKey))) {
            return false;
        }

        if (this.IsExpired(token)) {
            return false;
        }

        if (!this.IsIssuerTrusted(token)) {
            return false;
        }

        if (!this.IsAudienceTrusted(token)) {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    public Dictionary<string, string> GetNameValues(string token) {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(token)) {
            throw new ArgumentException();
        }

        return
             token
             .Split('&')
             .Aggregate(
             new Dictionary<string, string>(),
             (dict, rawNameValue) => {
                 if (rawNameValue == string.Empty) {
                     return dict;
                 }

                 string[] nameValue = rawNameValue.Split('=');

                 if (nameValue.Length != 2) {
                     throw new ArgumentException("Invalid formEncodedstring - contains a name/value pair missing an = character");
                 }

                 if (dict.ContainsKey(nameValue[0]) == true) {
                     throw new ArgumentException("Repeated name/value pair in form");
                 }

                 dict.Add(HttpUtility.UrlDecode(nameValue[0]), HttpUtility.UrlDecode(nameValue[1]));
                 return dict;
             });
    }

    private static ulong GenerateTimeStamp() {
        // Default implementation of epoch time
        TimeSpan ts = DateTime.UtcNow - new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0);
        return Convert.ToUInt64(ts.TotalSeconds);
    }

    private bool IsAudienceTrusted(string token) {
        Dictionary<string, string> tokenValues = this.GetNameValues(token);

        string audienceValue;

        tokenValues.TryGetValue(this.audienceLabel, out audienceValue);

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(audienceValue)) {
            if (audienceValue.Equals(this.trustedAudienceValue, StringComparison.Ordinal)) {
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

    private bool IsIssuerTrusted(string token) {
        Dictionary<string, string> tokenValues = this.GetNameValues(token);

        string issuerName;

        tokenValues.TryGetValue(this.issuerLabel, out issuerName);

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(issuerName)) {
            if (issuerName.Equals(this.trustedTokenIssuer)) {
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

    private bool IsHMACValid(string swt, byte[] sha256HMACKey) {
        string[] swtWithSignature = swt.Split(new string[] { "&" + this.hmacSHA256Label + "=" }, StringSplitOptions.None);

        if ((swtWithSignature == null) || (swtWithSignature.Length != 2)) {
            return false;
        }

        HMACSHA256 hmac = new HMACSHA256(sha256HMACKey);

        byte[] locallyGeneratedSignatureInBytes = hmac.ComputeHash(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(swtWithSignature[0]));

        string locallyGeneratedSignature = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(Convert.ToBase64String(locallyGeneratedSignatureInBytes));

        return locallyGeneratedSignature == swtWithSignature[1];
    }

    private bool IsExpired(string swt) {
        try {
            Dictionary<string, string> nameValues = this.GetNameValues(swt);
            string expiresOnValue = nameValues[this.expiresLabel];
            ulong expiresOn = Convert.ToUInt64(expiresOnValue);
            ulong currentTime = Convert.ToUInt64(GenerateTimeStamp());

            if (currentTime > expiresOn) {
                return true;
            }

            return false;
        } catch (KeyNotFoundException) {
            throw new ArgumentException();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Robar for reply and sorry for my late reply actually i got busy in some other assignmnet.

Comment: Thanks Robar for reply and sorry for my late reply actually i got busy in some other assignment. But i have question. When i configure my relying party to return SAML1.1 or SAML2.0 token. Then on client side i did get any token value. But When i configure Relying Party to return SWT token i do get the token on client side but in your class you are only processing the saml11 and saml12 token at        

if (tokenType == SecurityTokenTypes.Saml11 || tokenType == SecurityTokenTypes.Saml2)

So could you help me for SWT token please

Comment: I'm currently at work. When I get home, I'll look up some of my old projects and see if I find anything useful for your SWT token problem.

Comment: I've found something, I hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for reply,
I know the two classes that you send will be used on Service side so that each SWT token will be authenticated by these classes. But if see your JsonNotifyRequestSecurityTokenResponse class there you are populating SecurityToken only if "(tokenType == SecurityTokenTypes.Saml11 || tokenType == SecurityTokenTypes.Saml2)". So the token that I are returing is SWT so now how to extract securitytoken out of it. Is that make sense to you.

Comment: I don't know if I can help you any further with this. Maybe it'll work if you add the SWT token type to the if clause. I can't test it anymore because I don't have access to ACS anymore, since my company decided not to use it. Maybe some of those MSDN tutorials  (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh289317.aspx) are helpful.